# Get value of an radio button added after loading the page

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel

I work on a form that includes several subforms that are loaded as and when the responses of the users.
Typically
- according to the choice 1 of the user I display a form 2
- according to the choice of the form 2 I display a form 3 etc ...

The forms are loaded progressively via ajax/jquery.

On the other hand I keep in session all the answers in order to be able to redisplay the prefilled form if it is needed.

I encounter a problem when the user refreshes the page for example. In this case it happens:

- loading the entire page without any form
- then call via ajax the first part of the form which contains radio buttons. 
  As the form is already filled one of the radio buttons is already checked
- Then I can not recover the value of the radio button checked with jquery for to load the next form.

My form (content inside div loaded via ajax)

```
             <div id="enfant{{$i}}datesejour" class="datesej">

            </div>

            <div id="enfant{{$i}}semainesejour" class="">

            </div>

            <div id="enfant{{$i}}transportaller" class="">

            </div>

            <div id="enfant{{$i}}transportretour" class="">

            </div>
```

Radio button loaded in first div :

```
 <input id="datesejour_{{ $date->id }}_{{$i}}_{{$centre->id}}" name="enfant[{{$i}}][iddatesejour]" type="radio" value="{{ $date->id }}" class="sejdate"  @if   (Session::get('panier.0.enfant' .$i.'.idsejour') == $date->id) checked @endif>
```

I tried to use delegated event but it need.... an event. In my case there is no event because radio button is loaded after page load and they are checked witout user action.

I add the full code when page is loaded

```
<form action="http://gocolo.test/customer/inscription-4" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="xfU1YecncfmNBg27wuIM50e8UM7w6jFZ0raWIPAF">        
        <div id="enfant[1]">
            <input type="hidden" id="enfant[1][idenfant]" name="enfant[1][idenfant]" class="form-control" value="512">
            <input type="hidden" id="enfant[1][num]" name="enfant[1][num]" class="form-control" value="1">


            <div class="form-group ">
                <label for="enfant[1][nomenfant]">Nom de l'enfant*</label>
                <input type="text" id="enfant[1][nomenfant]" name="enfant[1][nomenfant]" class="form-control" value="christophe contard">
                                    <p class="helper-block">

                </p>
            </div>



            <div class="form-group ">
                <label for="periodesejour">Durée du séjour</label>
                <select id="1_periodesejour" name="enfant[1][periodesejour]" class="form-control getdate">
                    <option value="" disabled="" selected="">Sélectionner</option>
                                                <option value="Février">Fevrier</option>
                                                <option value="Pâques">Pâques</option>
                                                <option value="Eté" selected="">Eté</option>
                                                <option value="Toussaint">Toussaint</option>
                                        </select>
                                </div>

            <div class="form-group ">
                <label for="dureesejour">Durée du séjour</label>
                <select id="1_dureesejour" name="enfant[1][dureesejour]" class="form-control getdate">
                    <option value="" disabled="" selected="">Sélectionner</option>
                                                <option value="1 semaine" selected="">1 semaine</option>
                                                <option value="2 semaines">2 semaines</option>
                                                <option value="3 semaines">3 semaines</option>
                                        </select>
                                </div>


            <div id="enfant1datesejour" class="datesej"><div class="form-group">
    <label> bourboule</label>
            <div>

            <input id="datesejour_3_1_1" name="enfant[1][iddatesejour]" type="radio" value="3" class="sejdate">
            <label for="datesejour_3">Du 01-05-2019 au 08-05-2019</label>
        </div>

    </div>

            <div class="form-group">
    <label> moulibez</label>
            <div>

       <input id="datesejour_4_1_2" name="enfant[1][iddatesejour]" type="radio" value="4" class="sejdate" checked="">
            <label for="datesejour_4">Du 06-07-2019 au 13-07-2019</label>
        </div>

    </div>



</div>
            <div id="enfant1semainesejour" class=""></div>

            <div id="enfant1transportaller" class="">

            </div>

            <div id="enfant1transportretour" class="">

            </div>


        </div>
            <div>
        <input class="btn btn-danger" type="submit" value="Enregistrer">
    </div>

</form>


    </div>


</main>


<script>

    $(document).ready(function () {

        $('.getdate').each(function(  ) {
            var id2 = $(this).attr('id');
            var id3 = id2.split('_', 2);
            var id = id3['0']; // on recupere l'id de l'enfant
            var periode = $('#' + id + '_periodesejour').val();
            var duree = $('#' + id + '_dureesejour').val();
            getDate(id, periode, duree)
        });
    });






    $('.getdate').change(function () {

        var id2 = $(this).attr('id');
        var id3 = id2.split('_', 2);
        var id = id3['0']; // on recupere l'id de l'enfant
        var periode = $('#' + id + '_periodesejour').val();
        var duree = $('#' + id + '_dureesejour').val();
        getDate(id, periode, duree)
    });


    $(".datesej").on('change', '.sejdate', function () {
        // on recupere l'id du séjour
        var id2 = $(this).attr('id');
        var id3 = id2.split('_', 4);
        var idsejour = id3['1']; // on recupere l'id du sejour
        var id = id3['2']; // on recupere l'id de l'enfant

        var centreid = id3['3']; // on recupere l'id du centre
        getThemeTransport(idsejour, id, centreid)
    });

    function getThemeTransport(idsejour, id, centreid) {
        $.ajax({
            headers: {'x-csrf-token': _token},
            type: "POST",
            url: "/customer/getsemainetransport",
            data: {idsejour: idsejour, centreid: centreid, enfant: id}
        }).done(function (data) {
            ///  console.log(data);
            $('#enfant' + id + 'semainesejour').html(data);

        });

    }


    function getDate(id, periode, duree) {
        $.ajax({
            headers: {'x-csrf-token': _token},
            type: "POST",
            url: "/customer/getdatesejours",
            data: {periode: periode, duree: duree, enfant: id}
        }).done(function (data) {
            ////  console.log('#enfant' + id + 'datesejour');
            $('#enfant' + id + 'datesejour').html(data);
            $('#enfant' + id + 'semainesejour').empty();
        });
    }


</script>
```

Comment: Can you provide the event listener code for radio button? or you can output the filled forms when page is loading via php.

Comment: added in the edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this in your script:

```
window.onload = function(){
   if($(".sejdate:checked").val() != undefined){
     $(".sejdate:checked").trigger("change");
   }
};
```

You can modify your function slightly so that when form 2 is loaded check if there is any radio selected on form 2 if there is trigger another change to fetch form 3

Comment: I just add  $(".sejdate:checked").trigger("change"); in my function and it's ok.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [localStorage](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_win_localstorage.asp) or [sessionStorage](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_win_sessionstorage.asp)

by doing this

```
// first you have to use inline onclick events handler for all radio buttons
       <input id="datesejour_4_1_2" onclick="storeThis(this)" name="enfant[1][iddatesejour]" type="radio" value="4" class="sejdate" checked="">
// define the function storeThis in javascript section
<script>
function storeThis(e){

    if ($(e).is(':checked'))
    {
      sessionStorage.setItem($(e).attr('id'),1);
    } else {
      sessionStorage.setItem($(e).attr('id'),0);
    }

}

// create a function to check for radio buttons in sessionStorage based on their ids
function checkRadioButtons(){
    $('[type="radio"]').each(function(){
       if(sessionStorage.get($(this).attr('id')){
          $(this).prop("checked",true);
       } else {
          $(this).prop("checked",false);
       }
     }
}

// call checkRadioButtons after appending the new radio buttons
function getThemeTransport(idsejour, id, centreid) {
        $.ajax({
            headers: {'x-csrf-token': _token},
            type: "POST",
            url: "/customer/getsemainetransport",
            data: {idsejour: idsejour, centreid: centreid, enfant: id}
        }).done(function (data) {
            ///  console.log(data);
            $('#enfant' + id + 'semainesejour').html(data);
            checkRadioButtons();
        });

    }


    function getDate(id, periode, duree) {
        $.ajax({
            headers: {'x-csrf-token': _token},
            type: "POST",
            url: "/customer/getdatesejours",
            data: {periode: periode, duree: duree, enfant: id}
        }).done(function (data) {
            ////  console.log('#enfant' + id + 'datesejour');
            $('#enfant' + id + 'datesejour').html(data);
            $('#enfant' + id + 'semainesejour').empty();
            checkRadioButtons();
        });
    }

</script>
```

I hope my answer helps ^^